# On modifying a bibliography style (bst) file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have recently written a survey article for some journal. The problem is that they have not given their bibliography style file. However they have given in their preferred format for the bibliography. These are as follows.

Listing alphabetically, and numerical reference.  For paper the whole thing should come as like

1. Chen, T., Frohlich, J., Walcher, J.: The decay of unstable noncommutative   solitons. Commun. Math. Phys. 237, 243–269 (2003)

Of course, arXiv entries should also be accommodated in a similar way.

For books

2. Andrews, G.E., Askey, R., Roy, R.: Special Functions. Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge (1999)

And for conference proceedings

3. Buslaev,  V.S.,  Perel’man,  G.S.:  On  the  stability  of  solitary  waves  for  nonlinear Schrodinger equations, in “Nonlinear Evolution Equations”. Am. Math. Soc. Transl. Ser. 2 (164), 75–98 (1995)

Closest format of this strange style is acm, though the year has to be put at the end of each entry. Further I would like to have doi/url links highlighting the title of the paper (not as a separate entry like in most of the AMS publications). Since the number of bibliography entries are so large, I can not do it by hand.

So can someone suggest me, how to modify acm style such that it takes care of all the above mentioned points? Advanced thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: You can do all this in biblatex, and I'm fairly sure most of the specific points have been asked before, but it's worth checking that you can actually complete a submission if you rely on biblatex.  Many journals with TeX submission routes require embedded bilbiographies (these aren't too hard to generate if you're using bibtex).  They tend to compile automatically in house so anything too complex that you do will break.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Further I would like to have doi/url links highlighting the title of the paper".

Comment: @Mico acm style file did not allow any hyper-link to be put for the papers. I wanted to put those links.

Comment: @RSG - If you use the `makebst` utility to create a new bst file from scratch, it will provide a couple of questions on whether you want the bibliography style to recognize fields such as `doi` and `url`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than take an existing bst file and adjust it in various places to achieve your bibliographic formatting needs, I would like to recommend you create a new bibliography style file that immediately implements all of your formatting requirements.

This is actually much less difficult to achieve than it may sound: Just run the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. Type `latex makebst` at a command prompt to start the interactive question-and-answer process, and select a suitable answer from the menu of answers to each question. For each question, there's a default answer (marked with an asterisk) that may be chosen simply by hitting "return". At the end of this process, the `makebst` utility will create a bst file that implements all of your formatting requirements.