# Invert First authors last name and initials in references using bibtex

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, elsarticle

I am using bibtex, the `elsarticle` document class, and the `elsarticle-num-names` bibliography style. Is there a way to have your references like this:

> Singer, A., Z. Schuss, D. Holcman, 2006. Narrow escape, Part III: Non-smooth
>   domains and Riemann surfaces, Journal of Statistical Physics 122 (3) 491–509

instead of

> A. Singer, Z. Schuss, D. Holcman, Narrow escape, Part III: Non-smooth
>   domains and Riemann surfaces, Journal of Statistical Physics 122 (3)
>   (2006) 491–509.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{float}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}

\begin{document}

BLABLABLA \cite{singer2006narrowescape3}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names} 
\bibliography{mybib} 

\end{document}
```

The bib file `mybib.bib` contains the following entry:

```
@article{singer2006narrowescape3,
  title={Narrow escape, Part III: Non-smooth domains and Riemann surfaces},
  author={Singer, A and Schuss, Z and Holcman, D},
  journal={Journal of Statistical Physics},
  volume={122},
  number={3},
  pages={491--509},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. As always when it's necessary to make more than just one change to an existing bibliography style, it turns out to be much easier (and less error-prone!) to run the `makebst` utility (part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package) and create a new bibliography style file from scratch.

Comment: Hi! Can you expand a bit more on how to do this?

Comment: Please see, e.g., the answer to [On modifying a bibliography style (bst) file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310993/5001) for a (very brief) introduction to the idea of the `makebst` utility. I assume that it's not just the formatting of the entries of `@article` that you are looking to modify, right?

Comment: By the way, the title of your posting is a bit misleading. You're looking to change not only the order of first initial and surname of the first author but also the placement of the publication's year, right? Moreover, you're looking to suppress the trailing `.` ("dot", "period") at the end of the formatted entry, right?