# How to force a reference to have a specific format in BibTex

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to add the following reference to my work:

Walenski  M,  Tager-Flusberg  H,  Ullman  MT.  Language  in  autism.  In:  Moldin  S,  Rubenstein  JLR,  editors. *Understanding Autism: From Basic Neuroscience to Treatment.* Boca Raton, FL: Taylor and Francis; 2006. p. 175-203.

I want it to look exactly like the above. The current BibTex entry I have looks like this:

```
@inbook{moldin2006understanding,
  title={Understanding autism: from basic neuroscience to treatment},
  chapter = {Language  in  autism.},
  author={Moldin, Steven O and Rubenstein, John LR},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Taylor and Francis}
}
```

But when I `\cite{moldin2006understanding}` I get the following result in the references:

Steven O Moldin and John LR Rubenstein.*Understanding autism: from basic neuroscience to treatment*, chapter Language in autism.  Taylor and Francis, 2006.

How do I change this? More generally, how can I force any BibTex entry to spit out exactly the string I want?

Comment: you are missing the `editor`, `address` and `pages` fields. As for the exact look, it is not easy unless the style you want to mimic is a standard style. Otherwise, you would have to come up with your own .bst file (which defines the look of the output) but it is not straightforward.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ at present?

Comment: One reason for getting such a big discrepancy is that you're almost certainly using the incorrect entry type: It should be `@incollection`, *not* `@inbook`.

Comment: @Mico if I were to use ```@incollection```, how do I specify the chapter authors, as opposed to the book authors?

Comment: @Mico I use the ```unsrt``` style

Comment: @Sam - Use `author` for the chapter authors, `title` for the chapter name, `editor` for what you currently have as `author`, and `booktitle` for what you currently have as `title`.

Comment: The `unsrt` bib style is definitely not going to get the job done for you. The `elsarticle-num` or `elsarticle-harv` bib styles come a lot closer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your suggested approach fixed some aspects of the problem. However, the journal name is no longer italicized; and for some reason, the author names are not in the correct order of authorship. Is this expected?

Comment: @Sam - Chances that any existing bibliography style will match all of your formatting requirements -- many (most?) of which you haven't stated so far --  are pretty much nil. See [On modifying a bibliography style (bst) file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310993/5001) and especially [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311005/5001) for an alternative to hacking an existing bibliography style file.